# how to display blob type images stored in MySql database on a jquerymobile template

Tags: php, jquery, json, html, blob

I have a scenario where images should be displayed in my Jquerymobile template. These images come from MySQL database. Image type is blob type, and I am using PHP to retrieve my data - as follows

```
    <?php
include 'configure.php';
$qr = "SELECT * FROM food_beverage";
$res= mysql_query($qr);
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$restau_arr[$i]["fb_sno"] = $row["fb_sno"];
$restau_arr[$i]["fb_name"] = $row["fb_name"];
$restau_arr[$i]["fb_type"] = $row["fb_type"];
$restau_arr[$i]["fb_location"] = $row["fb_location"];
$restau_arr[$i]["fb_img"]= $row["fb_img"];
$restau_arr[$i]["fb_phno"]= $row["fb_phno"];
$restau_arr[$i]["fb_email"]= $row["fb_email"];
$i++;
}
 header('Content-type: application/json'); 
  echo json_encode($restau_arr);
?>
```

The values from database are stored in an array, and are being converted to JSON format so that I can call them using the following jquery lines -

```
var url = "retrieve_all.php";   
     $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                 .......
                  .......
                   ....... }
```

Once the values are received at this function, am appending them to respective HTML fields using -

```
 $.each(json, function(i,v) {                                     
                    var restauName = v.fb_name;
                    var restauLoc = v.fb_location;
                    var restauNum = v.fb_phno;
                                    var restauImg = v.fb_img;
                    $("#restauName").html(restauName);
                    $("#restauLoc").html(restauLoc);
                    $("#restauNum").html(restauNum);
                    $("#restauImg").html(restauImg);
                    });
```

I am able to understand that the image should NOT be taken as a JSON format. But how can this be dealt?
What should I do in PHP to get my blob image displayed on my page/screen?

Is the approach correct?

For this, I [checked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491522/how-to-display-images-stored-in-a-mysql-database-using-php) for help in the beginning, but my scenario seemed to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of notes that will give you a solution, than "click here for results"; but try this:

- Aside from the images you have a functioning solution?
- Are the images large?

  - If they are icons, I would embed the image data in the same JSON response (see end)
  - If they are photos, I would return an URL, and have a second HTTP request to download them. You can attach <img> elements to a document via AJAX response handlers.
  - The image serving script would take the ID, validate it, then return the DB field value.
  - You will need to ensure there is no charset conversion on your binary data, or the images will be corrupted.

To embed everything in a single response

- [rfc2397](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397)
- Make the image JSON item look like:

  - `data:image/jpeg;base64,base_64_encoded_jpeg_goes_here`
  - Obviously you can change the mime encoding to suit your needs.
- Add some JS to take this string, append an <img> element, with that data as the src attribute.

I have a rough demo of [JSON to img elements](http://owenberesford.me.uk/17690427/sample.html) (with external files).

Comment: thanks for your response. that makes a great help.. it would be more helpful with a working example. anyway, thanks for ur time again.